# Unanswered questions filters don't work

Tags: bug, unanswered-questions, filtering

I tried to filter unanswered questions to specific tags, like so. I used UI filter on this page:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Unanswered

I chose some options and the URL were generated:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions?uqlId=&filterId=NoAnswers&sortId=MostVotes&tagModeId=Specified&tagQuery=java

Unfortunately questions aren't filter to specific tag (first question is still Scala) and doesn't respect "No Answers" filter (first question still has answer).

Tested on Microsoft Edge 25.10586.672.0

PS. There were reports of problems with multiple tags, but I didn't find one with single tag and "No Answer" filter problems.

Comment: When I follow the steps of applying the filter it works for me, but after selecting the java tag filter and hitting the apply filter button I ended up on a different URL than you (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java?sort=MostVotes&filters=NoAnswers&edited=true).

Comment: @Gimby Your URL works for me. I tested again and creating filter like I described doesn't work correctly.