# "Unanswered" filter on specific tags doesn't work in mobile web

Tags: support, bug, tags, mobile-web, filtering

Unanswered tag can't be selected.If I select Unanswered that changes to Votes.Same bug reported long time ago, but still not fixed.

- [Bug in Tagged Questions filter / show in Unanswered Tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/391785/12731030)
- [Unanswered questions filters don't work](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386220/12731030)

However, When I use the following link, it works.(found from the second question listed above)

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php?sort=MostVotes&filters=NoAnswers&edited=true

How can I build links like that ? What are the parameters ? As an example, I need to find `Unanswered least votes` posts ?

Comment: I don't see Least Votes in the Sort By list of available items. Basically, visit that page in desktop, use the UI to configure the query the way you want, select Apply filter, copy/bookmark the URL.